# php: save server method after redirection

Tags: php, html

I don't know if this technique is correct. Anyway, on my page I have a submit button. An extract of the php code is the following:

```
<?php
$isPost = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, "REQUEST_METHOD", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) == "POST";

if ($isPost) {
  // do something...      
  header("Location: " . filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, "REQUEST_URI", FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
  exit();
}
```

In this way I'm avoiding the annoying issue of resend the post data when the user refresh the page.

One drawback, of course, is now the value of request method variable, retrieved *inside* the html page will be always "GET".

It would be nice a way to keep it, for example to show an alert that the data were saved:

```
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade <?php echo (filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, "REQUEST_METHOD", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) == "POST") ? "show" : "" ?> " role="alert">
    Settings successfully saved.
</div>
```

This doesn't work because it never evaluates as "POST"!
An ugly drawback (and quite prone to bugs) is to use the local storage of the browser to set a flag when the php code discover that was a "POST".

Is there something better?

Comment: Have you considered using $_SESSION ?

Comment: I didn't know it, thanks! - anyway it works like the local storage workaround, server side instead of client side. I'm wondering if this is the usual solution for the example above.

Comment: Its not a workaround, its a resource for information storage. You can use it to store messages to your users, and then, in your views, you show the messages stored. After the deliver, you may want to clean up the store to avoid showing the same message in every page. Btw, you can also send the POST dynamically via Javascript (aka ajax call) to server and make it deliver a json with the result. Just work in the json to show the returned message.

Comment: Got it. If you make it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose to you two alternatives:

### Use `$_SESSION`

`$_SESSION` is a resource for information storage. You can use it to store messages to your users, and then, in your views, you show the messages stored. After the deliver, you may want to clean up the store to avoid showing the same message in every page.

### Do a Dynamic Request

You can also send the POST dynamically via Javascript (aka AJAX call) to server and make it deliver a JSON with the result. Just work in the JSON to show the returned message.